# using curllib to send data to server

Tags: sockets, http, curl, tcp, client

I am very new to all this http thing and I am trying to make communication with a server.

I need to write the client that post to server - I know what server returns but I am not sure how to send it the data:

1. I (the client) Post XML (binary format) to server at url: `192.168.2.111/senddata` (i.e post /senddata) using HTTP.
2. Server response is:

   ```
   TCP: [ACK] Seq=1274 Ack=504 Win=525088 Len=0
   ```

   I.E here is the problem - the server does not reply with HTTP reply.
   The protocol server uses after I send it the XML is TCP and this makes `curl_easy_perform`
   to not return.
3. After server TCP reply in step 2, I-the client should send binary data in a loop to server using HTTP Continuation or non-HTTP traffic.
4. Server asynchronicity answers with

   ```
   TCP: [ACK] Seq=1274 Ack=3424 Win=522176 Len=0
   ```

   for each binary data sending .

So to send the XML in step 1, I use

```
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_URL, "192.168.2.111");
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST /senddata");
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, sXML.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, sXML.length());

headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept:");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, (string("Content-Length: ") + string(to_string(sXML.length()))).c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

res = curl_easy_perform(mCurlHndl);
```

Server does send in reply the:

```
TCP: [ACK] Seq=1274 Ack=504 Win=525088 Len=0
```

(just with other seq/ack/win numbers of course).

OK, here starts the problems.

a. `curl_easy_perform` does not return since (I think) server reply was not HTTP, but TCP.

b. OK, lets say that i can bypass it giving Timeout

```
    curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);
```

But i just know that i am doing something wrong.

c. Lets say I gave the timeout, now in step 3 I need to send in a loop stream of data using HTTP Continuation or non-HTTP traffic.

I do not know how to do that since it should not be regular post again like in step 1.
It should be HTTP Continuation or non-HTTP traffic.

Sorry for my bad explanation but again it is from my very little experience in HTTP.

Seems that after step 1, server breaks that normal http connection rules and what I need to send it is the binary data in a loop but again, i do not know how to do step 2 and 3. I.E how to get the TCP ACK from server using curllib that I will know to move to step 3 and how to (step 3) send to server over the same connection (I think) the binary data in loop.

I want to add that servers returns what is supposed to return. in step 2 server should return the TCP: [ACK] Seq=1274 Ack=504 Win=525088 Len=0 since this is what server should do - this is that server protocol. It is not that i do not send it right (in step 1) and that is why it send TCP reply and not http.

Here is Wireshark log:
192.168.2.7 is the client (that works).
192.168.2.111 is the server.
in the first line (seq 9)  the clinet post  the binary xml (POST /senddata) and then the loop of binary data stream sending starts as you can see:

```
9   0.173574000 192.168.2.7     192.168.2.111   HTTP    380     POST /senddata HTTP/1.1  (application/octet-stream)
10  0.176611000 192.168.2.111   192.168.2.7     TCP     60      4089 > 53419 [ACK] Seq=1274 Ack=504 Win=525088 Len=0
11  0.182581000 192.168.2.111   192.168.2.7     UDP     90      Source port: 4020  Destination port: 4005
12  0.553367000 192.168.2.7     192.168.2.111   HTTP    1354    Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
13  0.553403000 192.168.2.7     192.168.2.111   HTTP    1354    Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
14  0.555539000 192.168.2.111   192.168.2.7     TCP     60      4089 > 53419 [ACK] Seq=1274 Ack=3424 Win=522176 Len=0
15  0.555698000 192.168.2.7     192.168.2.111   HTTP    1354    Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
16  0.555724000 192.168.2.7     192.168.2.111   HTTP    1354    Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
17  0.555724000 192.168.2.7     192.168.2.111   HTTP    1354    Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
18  0.555724000 192.168.2.7     192.168.2.111   HTTP    1354    Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
19  0.558870000 192.168.2.111   192.168.2.7     TCP     60      4089 > 53419 [ACK] Seq=1274 Ack=6344 Win=519248 Len=0
20  0.559033000 192.168.2.7     192.168.2.111   HTTP    1354    Continuation or non-HTTP traffic

..... and many other sends like seq 12 - seq 20 ........
```

How do i do something like this with curllib - this is my question.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You are not using curl correctly for sending an HTTP `POST` request.  Try this instead:

```
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.2.111/senddata");
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, sXML.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, sXML.length());

struct curl_slist *headers = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept:");
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

res = curl_easy_perform(mCurlHndl);
curl_slist_free_all(headers);

// process reply using curl_easy_getinfo() and curl_easy_recv() as needed...
```

With that said, are you sure that you should be sending the `Content-Type` as `application/octet-stream`?  Typically XML is posted using `text/xml`, `application/xml`, or other XML-related `Content-Type` so the server knows it is dealing with XML data.  `application/octet-stream` refers to arbitrary binary data when its actual type is not known.

Also, setting the `Accept` header to a blank value basically means you do not accept any data in reply.  Unless you want to accept only specific `Content-Type` reply types, or want to accept any data the server wants to send, then you should omit the `Accept` header.

Read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) for the formal definition of the HTTTP protocol and how it works.

**Update**: since you are obviously dealing with a custom protocol and not standard HTTP, you cannot use `curl_easy_perform()` to send the HTTP request.  You will have to enable the `CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY` option so `curl_easy_perform()` will only open the socket connection, and then use `curl_easy_send()` to send the actual request and subsequent binary data, eg:

```
CURLcode curl_send(CURL *curl, const void * buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    size_t sent;

    uint8_t *pbuf = (uint8_t*) buffer;
    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        do
        {
            res = curl_easy_send(curl, pbuf, buflen, &sent); 
        }
        while (res == CURLE_AGAIN);

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            return res;

        pbuf += sent;
        buflen -= sent;
    }
    while (buflen > 0);

    return CURLE_OK;
}
```

```
mCurlHndl = curl_easy_init();

...

curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.2.111");
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1);

res = curl_easy_perform(mCurlHndl);
if (res == CURLE_OK)
{
    string req =
        "POST /senddata HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
        "Content-Length: " + to_string(sXML.length()) + "\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        + sXML;

    res = curl_send(mCurlHndl, req.c_str(), req.length());
    if (res !- CURLE_OK) ...

    res = curl_send(mCurlHndl, ...binary data...);
    if (res !- CURLE_OK) ...

    res = curl_send(mCurlHndl, ...binary data...);
    if (res !- CURLE_OK) ...

    res = curl_send(mCurlHndl, ...binary data...);
    if (res !- CURLE_OK) ...
    ...
}

...

curl_easy_cleanup(mCurlHndl);
```

Comment: Hi Remy.
In your answer you focused on step 1 from the 4 steps, but as explain there is no problem with step 1. yes i need application/octet-stream since i send the XML in binary format.
As said, there is no problem with step 1. Yes i can use curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.2.111/senddata"); to make step 1, but again, both gives me same results - there is no problem with that step. I need help with step 2-4.

Thanks again for answering.

Comment: I want to add that servers returns what is supposed to return. in step 2 server should return the TCP: [ACK] Seq=1274 Ack=504 Win=525088 Len=0 since this is what server should do - this is that server protocol. It is not that i do not send it right (in step 1) and that is why it send TCP reply and not http.

Comment: And one more thing Remy, even with your answer, curl_easy_perform still will not return since server by designed is not replying with http header but as written it sends tcp ack reply.

Comment: You are focusing on the TCP packet headers and not on the TCP payload data. Two separate things. An HTTP server WILL NOT send a 0-byte TCP packet in reply to an HTTP request. The real reply packets will contain an HTTP reply payload. You are looking at TCP's acknowledgements of the TCP packets you are sending to the server. Those are not the same TCP packets that contain the server's real reply to your HTTP request. You need to pay attention to the packet payloads, not the packet headers. If you are using WireShark, use its "Follow TCP Stream" option to look at just the payload data by itself.

Comment: Hi Remy.
Yes i use WireShark. The specific server does that. I look as you say in the Follow TCP Stream and i see that the other clients that works with that server do what i wrote.
So to continue what you wrote, seems that client sends http post request http://192.168.2.111/senddata and server never response back with an http reply. and clients keeps sending the other binary data in a loop. that data is sent by client (as seen in WireShark) using Protocol:HTTP and in the INFO: 'Continuation or non-HTTP traffic' and as said, server send TCP acks asynchronicity  to all the sending in the loop

Comment: here is the "Follow TCP Stream" output:
----
POST /senddata HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 1056

Here come the binary data (a)
Here come the other binary data that is sent in a loop (b)
Here come the other binary data that is sent in a loop (c)
....
----
the Here come the binary data (a) - that seems to be sent in the Post packet. and then many http send with no headers (WireShhark calls it 'Continuation or non-HTTP traffic'):
Here come the other binary data that is sent in a loop (b)
Here come the other binary data that is sent in a loop (c)
.....

Comment: What you describe is incomplete. Please update your question to show the actual WireShark capture, or post a link to the capture file, for a working client. What you describe is NOT how a real HTTP server operates.

Comment: Remy, i know but as said, this is not regular HTTP client. That is why i have this problem and that is why i asked this question.

Comment: What you posted is still not useful. I need to see the **data** that is being transmitted, not the **TCP packet headers** (they are useless in this situation, *STOP FOCUSING ON THEM!*). "Continuation or non-HTTP traffic" simply means that data is spanning across multiple TCP packets, so Wireshark can't parse them as a group.

Comment: If I had to guess, the client is simply sending a large HTTP request using multiple writes on its socket. That would account for "Continuation" data, and would be handled by a `Content-Length` or `Tranfer-Encoding: chunked` header in the HTTP request (both of which curl supports). Without seeing the **data** that is transmitted, there is not way to verify that, or to say what code you need to use to mimic what other clients are actually doing.  Please show the **actual data** that is being transmitted, or upload the Wireshark file somewhere that it can be downloaded from for review.

Comment: Remy hi.
I can not send the data since it is not encrypted and contain private data.
The logs i added in the question the contain few rows that the first has sec 9 so if i write line 9 , then i mean to that first one and so on.
If you look in line 9, There client send the binary XML
The data that that packet contains is this and only this:
---- -------
POST /senddata HTTP/1.1 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream 
Content-Length: 1056 
Here come the the XML in binary format. XML size is the SAME as the Content-Length which is 1056
------------

[I Continue in the next comment below:]

Comment: This is all the data of line 9.
Then in line 12 client starts streaming binary data.
ALL the data that packet contains is the binary data. No headers.
When doing Follow TCP stream, I see that binary data of line 12 continues data of line 9, i.e
data of line 12 is appended to the data of line 9
So what you see is this:
POST /senddata HTTP/1.1 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream 
Content-Length: 1056 
[Here come XML in binary format. XML size is the SAME as the Content-Length which is 1056][here come binary data of line 12]
[binary data of line 13][data of line 15][data of line 16]...

Comment: To add that:
There is no Tranfer-Encoding: chunked in the TCP stream.

Comment: What you describe is **NOT** how standard HTTP works. To use curl with this obviously-custom protocol, you would not be able to use `curl_easy_perform()` to send the request (since it is going to perform a standard HTTP request and wait for a standard HTTP reply). You can use it to establish the underlying connection, but then you will have to use [`curl_easy_send()`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_send.html) instead to manually send the complete "HTTP" request, and then you can immediately send your binary data afterwards using the same connection.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that tomorrow and let you know.
I would appreciate if you continue to monitor this thread.
Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Remy. YES! that what i needed.
Small question: in line 9 client post data. in line 10 server send tcp ack. then in line 11 server send UDP reply on ANOTHER port then the port client used to post. how can i catch and get the data for this UDP reply server send after the post?

Comment: I tried this:
CURL* mCurlHndl_rcv = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl_rcv, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.192.168.2.111:4005");
curl_easy_setopt(mCurlHndl_rcv, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1);

res = curl_easy_perform(mCurlHndl_rcv);

CLIENT POST THE DATA as you wrote me.
THEN:
res = curl_easy_recv(mCurlHndl_rcv ...
 
but got UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL err from curl_easy_recv.
Could be that since it is UDP? I also not sure if i can recv the udp pck server sent just like this or if server already sent that udp before i called curl_easy_recv then i lost the package? (or it is saved in curl stack).

Comment: curl does not support UDP. Whatever the server is sending in that UDP packet is likely not related to this protocol. It could just be a stray ICMP packet or something. In the off-chance that it is required (maybe some kind of "go ahead" packet, which would not make sense), you will have to use a separate socket/library to receive it. If you read the documentation for [`curl_easy_recv()`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_recv.html), it says: "If there's no socket available to use from the previous transfer, this function returns CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL."

Comment: Just what kind of server exactly are you communicating with?  This is turning into a really ugly bastardized protocol, I can't fathom why anyone would have designed it this way instead of using a standardized protocol.

Comment: Hi Remy. 100% sure that i need the udp data.
What about something like this:
http://en.it-usenet.org/thread/17224/814/
I tried but without this line
long sockextr;
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_LASTSOCKET, &sockextr);
since i am not sure why he need sockextr if later he use curl_easy_recv
Get the unsupportd protocol err with it as well.

Comment: OK with that link i sent you i managed to not getting the unsupported error. but now curl_easy_recv returns only CURLE_AGAIN
Could be that since the udp packet is sent before i call curl_easy_recv then it is lost?

Comment: Again,  curl does not support UDP, so you **cannot** use `curl_easy_recv()` to receive that UDP packet. You need to use another socket API for that, such as your platform's standard `socket()` and `recvfrom()` functions. Even if curl supported UDP, you would not be able to use the same `mCurlHndle`, which is already associated with a TCP socket.

Comment: Since UDP is connectionless and unreliable, and the UDP packet is not being acked, there is no way for the server to know that it even reached your machine let alone that you actually read it. So I would suggest you just ignore it. Without showing the actual data in that packet, there is no way to know what it actually is.

Comment: Do you have some very very easy example for me how to write function GET_UDP_DATA(arr_byte_udp_data_to_recv);
I will call this function after i post to server. the function should not return till arr_byte_udp_data_to_recv array is filled with the udp data. Sorry if it sound trivial to you :) but since i just started to deal with http, everything that should take X minutes takes me X hours ...
Or maybe i will need to call this function in ANOTHER thread BEFORE posting to server so it will start receiving even before i post to server?

Comment: Just to add that i know what the udp data is for. the server send its current status like that - do not ask why :) anyway, it sends it every few seconds or so in case packet is lost so i need to catch that packet

Comment: UDP has nothing to do with HTTP. I already told you which functions to use for the UDP portion, please read available documentation for them. There are TONS of examples online. Yes, you would have to start listening for UDP data before sending the HTTP request (or in parallel to) to ensure you do not lose the UDP data (assuming it arrives at all, which is NOT GUARANTEED with UDP), and then send the binary data on the next available status update you receive.  You don't need another thread for that, though that is certainly an option.

Comment: This has already gone **FAR BEYOND** the scope of the original question.  Let's please end this.  If you have further questions, please post them separately.

Comment: OK, will try to find examples how to do that. THANKS again for all your help. again thank you so much !!!